# Node.js - Pug Template - Render href dynamically

Tags: node.js, pug, email-templates

I am having a API written in Node.js with Express.js and Mongoose. For the mailers, I use email-templates npm module. I use the PUG templating engine to present my email.

I pass some variables to the template and want to use that as href inside my emails.

Here is the code I am struggling with:

`locals: {
    name: obj.first_name + " " + obj.last_name,
    token: obj.token
}`

Here the data is being passed to the template from the node API.

and in the template:

`a.button(href='xyz.com/verify/#{token}', target='_blank') Activate your account`

It says invalid token at `#`. How do I solve this dynamically? However the #{name} is properly received and shown in the email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pug team removed the support for interpolation in attributes in Pug v2. You have to use another syntax for it.

You can either compose your string:

```
a.button(href='xyz.com/verify/' + token, target='_blank') Activate your account
```

Or else use ES2015 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) feature if your environment support it.

```
a.button(href=`xyz.com/verify/${token}`, target='_blank') Activate your account
```